# LinkedList iterating

Tags: java, linked-list, iteration

**I have these monsters in the LinkedList and it iterates through it. In addition to that I want my output to look like this:**

Screaming-Monster "Bob" with fightingpower 1

Fighting-Monster "Tom" with fightingpower 6

Fighting-Monster "Dave" with fightingpower 7

Scream-Fight-Monster "Steve" with fightingpower 3

**How do I archieve this?**

```
public class AdventureGame {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    LinkedList <String> monsterList = new LinkedList <String>();

    monsterList.add("Screaming-Monster \"Bob\"");
    monsterList.add("Fighting-Monster \"Tom\"");
    monsterList.add("Fighting-Monster \"Dave\"");
    monsterList.add("Scream-Fight-Monster \"Steve\"");

    for(int i=0; i<monsterList.size(); i++){
        System.out.println(monsterList.get(i));
    }
}}
```

Comment: Either change the strings to include the fightingpower values, or create a Monster class that takes a type, name, power, and has a meaningful `toString` method.

Comment: Do you have a more specific question that "how do I achieve this?" Or did you just want us to do your homework for you? Looks like you're off to a great start!

Comment: the specific question is: how do I do this with only one iteration AND not including the fightingpower values in the linkedlist

Answer (score 0):

You need to associate the 'fighting power' value with the monster, but you don't do this in your program. Values that relate to each other should be stored together. How about a class to represent a monster:

```
class Monster {
    private String name;
    private int fightingPower;

    public Monster(String name, int fightingPower) {
        this.name = name;
        this.fightingPower = fightingPower;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getFightingPower() {
        return fightingPower;
    }
}
```

Then you could make a list of `Monster`s like this:

```
LinkedList<Monster> monsterList = new LinkedList <Monster>();

monsterList.add(new Monster("Screaming-Monster \"Bob\"", 1));
monsterList.add(new Monster("Fighting-Monster \"Tom\"", 6));
monsterList.add(new Monster("Fighting-Monster \"Dave\"", 7));
monsterList.add(new Monster("Scream-Fight-Monster \"Steve\"", 3));
```

and you could print them out like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < monsterList.size(); i++){
    Monster monster = monsterList.get(i);
    System.out.println(monster.getName() + " with fightingpower " + monster.getFightingPower());
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I forgot you could make a linkedlist with an object type!

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a monster class that looks like this:

```
private String type;
private String name;
private int fightingpower;

monster(String type, String name, int fightingpower) {
    this.type = type;
    this.name = name;
    this.fightingpower = fightingpower;
}

public String getStats() {
    String stats = this.type + " \"" + this.name + "\" with fightingpower " + this.fightingpower;
    return stats;
}
```

then in your class with your LinkedList do:

```
LinkedList <monster> monsterList = new LinkedList <>();

monsterList.add(new monster("Screaming-Monster", "Bob", 1))
//Repeat for every monster you want to have

for (int i = 0; i < monsterList.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println(monsterList.get(i).getStats());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Further to @matt's fine answer, and as the title of your question is "LinkedList iterating", I'd like to point out that you should use a *for-each* loop to iterate over a linked list:

```
for (Monster monster : monsterList) {
    System.out.println(monster.getName() + " with fightingpower " 
        + monster.getFightingPower());
}
```

Using a *for-each* loop is O(n), while using an index and `get()` is O(1/2 n * n)